# Can't mount NTFS hard disk (LDM data partition, correct way to automatically create and mount an LDM at startup)

Tags: arch-linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

1. Install **ldmtool** and **libldm** packages
2. Create `/etc/systemd/system/ldmtool.service` file
3. Paste the text into file:

```ini
[Unit]  
Description= Windows Dynamic Disk LDMtool  
After=network.target  

[Service]  
Type=forking  
User=root  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ldmtool create all  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. `sudo systemctl enable ldmtool.service`
5. `sudo systemctl start ldmtool.service`
6. Then open **gnome-disk-utility**
7. Choose one of the volumes and press the buttons:
   [image]
8. Edit the mount point and name

[image]

Comment: Dynamic partitions are a proprietary Microsoft work around for the MBR primary partition limit. With UEFI and gpt partitioning, you do not need dynamic partitions. Better to jut convert back, but Microsoft has no undo. They recommend backup & repartitions. You still need good backups but some third party Windows tools may work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758